# Sheet select from a Userform button causes data entered to go on previous sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I call a macro called SelectSheet1, from a button on a userform, to select Sheet1.

When data is entered afterwards it is put on the previous sheet.

This is happening on Excel 2013. I confirmed it is not a problem in Excel 2007.

Also it is not a problem if the macro is run directly from the developer tab, keyboard shortcut, quick access toolbar or ribbon customization.

The userform command button code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call SelectSheet1
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

The SelectSheet1 macro selects the sheet:

```
Sub SelectSheet1()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```

[Link to xlsm file in dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yh864yfoeoaijn0/Test%20Dialog%20Button%20for%20Navigation.xlsm?dl=0)

[Link to youtube video if you want to see with your own eyes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p34IbXS98Xs)

It is a strange error and wondering if it a problem with Excel 2013, something changed in the way they do things and possibly there is a workaround.

Comment: The cells must be linked somehow, it is very strange

Comment: Nothing is linked,  it is just a strange glitch in Excel 2013 because its not a problem in Excel 2007.  I did notice something new... I tried in a new file and am having the same issue but  when I test the userform in debug window it does not have the problem,  but when I click a shape on a worksheet that shows the userform then I am having the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to get it to work, but not sure why this solves the issue.

Im unloading the Userform before call macro and I tried using select instead of Activate, those did not help.  But after I switched so that the UserForm loads with vbModeless then my problem went away, not sure why this fixed it.

For me the key to fixing this issue was vbModeless, but would love if somebody who understood more could explain why.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Unload UserForm1
  Call SelectSheet1
End Sub

Sub ShowMainMenu()
  UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Sub SelectSheet1()
  Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is only a single sheet **Select**'ed before you **Activate** a sheet:

```
Sub SelectSheet1()
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```

Remember:     *"Although only a single sheet may be Active, many may be Selected."*

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it did not help.  My code works in Excel 2007, so im wondering what happened in the newer version of Excel,  Im on Excel 2013/

Comment: @DDCPA-MBA-DBA I cannot test as I am on *Excel 2007*